# Iframe is not showing in Drupal site

Tags: html, drupal, iframe, module

I am using [Iframe Module](http://drupal.org/project/iframe) module for showing Iframe

Its showing Blank content section into the page to me.

Can any one know about that where I am doing wrong....

Comment: Problem is solved just Reactiving plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please Try to **Reactivate** your **IFRAME module** might be some Module installation problem or some parameter is not updated in Database

I had same problem and now its solved by reactivating module

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason would be the input formats. If iframes is not displayed as the input format is `Filtered HTML`, then you should probably try changing it to `Full HTML`.

Comment: I have same problem here 

But there is not content editor i just used iframe module and in that we just have to put url of that iframe
ONE more thing Its working on development site but not in Live site
I also try to Apply directly Development Database on Live site still got same problem

Comment: thanks Gokul, I made iframe as content editor so we just need to add path of iframe
so there is no relation with Editor.